# Why Observable is not collected if not saved internally, e.g. in a class variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The code below creates `Observable` that passes current `Date` every second. From the code below I see that `Observable<Date>` is returned from the `ObservableService` & subscribed right away in `AppComponent`. Although  `Observable<Date>` was not saved in AppComponent as a class internal variable, the app continues to receive notifications and the returned  `Observable<Date>` is not collected by the GC.

My question is why it is so, why `Observable<Date>` was not collected/removed when no object is referencing or capturing it? My main assumption here is that closure in `AppComponent` : `data => this.currentTime = data` captures this (`AppComponent`) but not vise versa. So as `Observable<Date>` is not captured in `AppComponent`, `Observable<Date>` should be removed soon after creation. However it does not happen. Again, what is the reason for this?

**observable.service.ts**

```
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';

export class ObservableService {

  createObservableService(): Observable<Date> {
    return new Observable(
      observer => {
        interval(1000)
          .subscribe((_) => observer.next(new Date()));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableService } from "./observable.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  providers: [ ObservableService ],
  template: `<h1>Custom observable service</h1>
       Current time: {{currentTime | date: 'mediumTime'}}
  `})
export class AppComponent {

  currentTime: Date;

  constructor(private observableService: ObservableService) {
    this.observableService.createObservableService()
      .subscribe( data => this.currentTime = data );
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ObservableService } from "./observable.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ObservableService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Because the observable is indirectly referenced by the browser scheduler (window.setInterval(), window.setTimeout()) used to schedule the action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Answer (score -1):

Only subscribe to an observable which completes. You can add a complete operator manually (we call that unsubscribe). However it is commonly more recommended to avoid subscriptions and use the async pipe instead. Example for async pipe:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableService } from "./observable.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  providers: [ ObservableService ],
  template: `<h1>Custom observable service</h1>
       Current time: {{currentTime$ | async | date: 'mediumTime'}}
  `})
export class AppComponent {

  currentTime$: Observable<Date>;

  constructor(private observableService: ObservableService) {
    this.currentTime$ = this.observableService.createObservableService();
  }
}
```

Comment: @downvoter what's the reason for the downvote? Please elaborate

Comment: The main reason is that it doesn't answer the question at all.